Influxdb: store data into influxdb from oracle database using apache airflow
I am using Apache airflow for storing data in influxdb from oracle database. I need to store all data from oracle database into influxdb. But it insert last row of data only each company_id. Other data not insert. Here is oracle data set:

Here is the python code :
        from airflow import DAG
    from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
    from airflow.providers.influxdb.hooks.influxdb import InfluxDBHook
    from airflow.providers.oracle.hooks.oracle import OracleHook
    from influxdb_client.client.write_api import SYNCHRONOUS
    from datetime import datetime,timedelta,timezone
    import influxdb_client
    import traceback

    bucket = "myBucket"
    org = "city"
    token = "LsOE3PsZjive2ENtJnM3Pv2UmxcygaLymDPpR2YJO0XBZa0eA=="
    url = "http://influxdb:8086"

    def get_data_from_oracle(**kwargs):
       
        oracle_hook = OracleHook(oracle_conn_id='oracle_default')
        sql = """
            SELECT COMPANY_ID,
           CREDIT_AMOUNT,
           CREDIT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
           DEBIT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
      FROM gtt_transaction
     WHERE     COMPANY_ID IN (969, 116)
           AND TRUNC (INSERT_DATE) = '15-AUG-2024'
           AND TRX_REFERENCE IN ('15082445361298', '15082439504163')
        """
        data = oracle_hook.get_pandas_df(sql)
        return data


    def transform_oracle_data(ti):
       
        data = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='getDataFromOracle_task')
        return data

    current_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc)


    def insert_data_into_influxdb(ti):
       
        data = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='transanformOracleData_task')
        print("insert_data_into_influxdb--data-",data)

        if data is None:
            print("No data received from transform_oracle_data_task")
            return  # Exit gracefully if no data

        try:
            client = influxdb_client.InfluxDBClient(url=url, token=token, org=org)
            write_api = client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)
            points = []
        
            for count, row in enumerate(data.to_records(index=False)):

                timestamp = current_time + timedelta(microseconds=count)
                print("timestamp--",timestamp)
                point = influxdb_client.Point("oracle_transactions_3") \
                    .tag("company_id", row.COMPANY_ID) \
                    .field("credit_amount", float(row.CREDIT_AMOUNT)) \
                    .field("credit_account_number", str(row.CREDIT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER)) \
                    .field("debit_account_number", str(row.DEBIT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER)) \
                    .time(timestamp, influxdb_client.WritePrecision.NS)
                points.append(point)
            write_api.write(bucket=bucket, org=org, record=points)  

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {traceback.format_exc()}")


    # DAG definition
    with DAG(
        dag_id='oracle_to_influxdb_line_protocol',
        start_date=datetime(2024, 8, 13),
        schedule_interval='*/50 * * * *',  
        catchup=False,
    ) as dag:

        get_data_from_oracle_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id='getDataFromOracle_task',
            python_callable=get_data_from_oracle,
        )

        transform_oracle_data_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id='transanformOracleData_task',
            python_callable=transform_oracle_data,
        )

        insert_data_into_influxdb_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id='insertIntoFluxDb_task',
            python_callable=insert_data_into_influxdb,
        )

        # Task dependencies
        get_data_from_oracle_task >> transform_oracle_data_task >> insert_data_into_influxdb_task

What is reason for inserting only one row?
I want to store all data found in query.
what is the wrong of my code?
Please help me...

how many rows are actually returned from the oracle query ?. test without the airflow part and see if it works.

@ticktalk thanks for your reply.  It  may be 1000, or 2000 or more. I have just provided the sample query. But data will be same like above sample. Data will be according to company_id. Here I have provided two company_id (116,969). it may be other company_id which come dynamically too.

It seems you are only ever writing the last point. You want to do something like this to write all the points (stored in a list) after the loop execution:
points = []
for count, row in enumerate(data.to_records(index=False)):
    # ... (rest of your code for creating the point)
    points.append(point)

write_api.write(bucket=bucket, org=org, record=points)

